# Are Tools/Products/Devices, when used by design, considered "Lifehacks"?

Tags: discussion, definition

In relation to these questions:

- [Should product recommendations be on-topic?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-product-recommendations-be-on-topic/35#35)
- [Do questions asking for common-sense advice really count as asking about lifehacks?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/do-questions-asking-for-common-sense-advice-really-count-as-asking-about-lifehac)...
- [Should we be downvoting conventional answers?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/should-we-be-downvoting-conventional-answers)

And these Meta discussions:

- [What is a lifehack?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-is-a-lifehack)
- [Should we be downvoting conventional answers?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/should-we-be-downvoting-conventional-answers)
- [Are devices considered life hacks?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-devices-considered-life-hacks)

#### Are product / tool / device specific answers (*when used by design*) acceptable?

Examples for definition purposes:

#### Tool

A simple everyday item you might use in a myriad of ways:

- A cup
- A "lever"
- A screwdriver
- A knife, et. al.

#### Product

A purchasable common household agent/chemical/solution (liquid, not answer) you could buy at a variety of common stores to assist in a task/chore:

- Window cleaner
- Ammonia
- Bleach
- Paint thinner
- Antifreeze, et. al.

#### Device

A contraption/mechanism designed with a specific purpose in mind

- A can opener
- A paper shredder
- A multimeter
- A potato peeler

I have seen/read examples of the Law of Parsimony/Ockhams razor used in here (The simplest answer is most likely the best/right one) yet I have seen mixed results throughout the site stating both sides of the argument of weather a product/tool/device, when used in it's intended way, is an acceptable answer.

A life-hack is just that; a hack. A creative/innovative way to circumvent/solve a problem.
Using toothpaste to fill nail holes, or chewed up paper is perfect example of a hack, however "purchasing spackle" isn't necessarily a hack but it solves the problem with the simple solution.

The dichotomy of the site seems to be "Simple solution to solve a problem" and "ingenious and creative way to solve a problem" We should set a precedent here as to our goal for the "Life Hack" amalgamation of those two terms.

If I want to clean my hands of sticky stuff a life hack isn't "buy a citrus cleaner". One of many life hack examples could be "use water and sand as make shift pumice to exfoliate"

If I want to remove lint from an iphone headphone jack - use tape wrapped inside out around a paperclip or toothpick...not "buy a lint removal tool"

#### HOWEVER...

If I suggest using a product / tool / device in an ingenious way because I have it lying around (If you are high-centered on a snowbank in winter without a shovel to dig out with, you can use any number of products/tools as a makeshift shovel)

Are we going to allow users to answer questions with product or tool/device recommendations when that said tool or product is specifically designed for that exact purpose? Isn't this going *against* the design of this SE site in the first place?

#### For example:

Using a cheese grater to grate cheese - ***unaceptable***?

Using a cheese grater to shred a credit card - ***acceptable***?

Comment: How do you define a tool/product/device?

Comment: Tool/Device could be used interchangebly i guess. I saw them defined as: a tool is a simple everyday item you might use (cup, lever, screwdriver, knife) a product is something you would buy (window cleaner, ammonia, paint thinner) a device is a contraption designed for a specific purpose (can opener, paper shredder, multimeter). Moving to the question for clarity

Comment: [Very related question](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1137/78)

Comment: @ZachSaucier moved to the question. TY.

Answer (score 2):

Although I've done this myself, you have a valid point. Although *I* have these things sitting around, they *were* manufactured for the purpose, and so aren't really hacks. They are the *regular* solution. We could define tool/product/device as:

- **Tool:**

  > a device or implement, especially one held in the hand, used to *carry out a particular function*
- **Product:**

  > something that is marketed or sold as a *commodity*
- **Device:**

  > an object, machine, or piece of equipment that has been made for *some special purpose*

Now all of these things, but especially product, has the potential to be used in a creative way, not the function they were designed for, and that creative use is, in my eyes, a valid lifehack.

We can discourage answers that suggest using a tool/product/device in the manner they were intended for/designed for. That is not a lifehack, it's common sense/the 'regular' solution.

Comment: I agree that DV the "common sense answer" may be the best solution, but not erase/remove the answer as it may be a regional issue (the orange peeler posit).

Comment: In cases in which the "regular" solution is most effective, what do you recommend?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I think this is still highly debated here. My opinion is that if it is the correct tool for the job then it isn't a hack. But in the case of "regular/designed solution" vs simplified solutions" vs "best solution" vs. "creative solution sans normal tool" I am still curious about that myself.

Comment: @Phlume I think determining what is the "regular/designed solution" is impossible to determine in most cases. See [this post](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/should-we-be-downvoting-conventional-answers/1139#1139) of mine for my reasoning

Comment: I agree in some cases, but not "most" cases. We as a human race have evolved quite well and adapted to problems over thousands of years. Simple machines (lever, wheel, pully...) have bene used for ages and solve a myriad of problems universally. However isolated minutia such as peeling oranges with an "orange peeler" (foreign to me, I use fingers) could find a variety of accepted "regular/designed" solutions. If an answer suggests a can opener to open a can, is this helping our "Lifehack" site? How about water and soap as a suggestion to clean sticky hands? Lifehacks IMHO should be "HACKY".